# JAMS Scheduler - Set parameters for unscheduled job from command line

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have a temp solution JAMS job that I'm manually submitting from command line (calling powershell) using `powershell.exe -command -Submit-JAMSEntry -Name "\path\jams\job" -Server "jams.server.name"`

This part works fine. However I'm unable to find out how to pass in values for the parameters I have set up in that JAMS job. Adding `-param "value"` to the above execution doesn't work. I need this to go through command line with the powershell.exe, and writing/executing a powershell script elsewhere is not available to me in this integration.

Comment: Being unfamiliar with JAMS, what would the full command look like if you were calling it directly from PowerShell?  `Submit-JAMSEntry -Name "\path\jams\job" -Server "jams.server.name" -param "value"`?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to use `-usevariables` and not `-parameters`

Answer (score 0):

Try this
-Submit-JAMSEntry -Name "\path\jams\job" -Server "jams.server.name"  **Set-JAMSParameter -Name "param" -Value "value"**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).